# rewrite PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled into PXUIEnabledAttribute

Tags: acumatica

Good day I strageling to write a PXUIEnabledAttribute for SOOrder.orderType
This is to limit the user of changing ordertype if (in this case) he has te warehouse role.

```
    protected void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {

        var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;

        string username = Base.Accessinfo.UserName;
        UsersInRoles a = PXSelect<UsersInRoles, Where2<Where<UsersInRoles.rolename, Equal<Required<UsersInRoles.rolename>>>,
                                                         And<UsersInRoles.username, Equal<Required<UsersInRoles.username>>>>>.Select(this.Base, "Warehousing", Base.Accessinfo.UserName);

        if (a != null)
        {
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOOrder.orderType>(cache, e.Row, false);

        }

    }
```

This code does work half the time. when navigating between records the code does not always work/fire.

I was hoping to swap the above code out with something in the line of:

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
[PXUIEnabled(add magic code here)]
protected virtual void SOOrder_OrderType_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{ }
```

But I am straggeling to create the PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Constant class for warehousing and username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem might be that you only set the field as disabled, but there is no other logic to enable it back (if a==null).

Therefore, change your code as follows:

```
   protected void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
        string username = Base.Accessinfo.UserName;
        UsersInRoles a = PXSelect<UsersInRoles, Where2<Where<UsersInRoles.rolename, 
                              Equal<Required<UsersInRoles.rolename>>>,
                              And<UsersInRoles.username,      
                              Equal<Required<UsersInRoles.username>>>>>
        .Select(this.Base, "Warehousing", Base.Accessinfo.UserName);

        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOOrder.orderType>(cache, e.Row, a == null);

        }
```

Regarding BQL constants, you can create a new BQLConstants class where you store your constants, like this:

```
public class BQLConstants
{
  public class warehousing: Constant<String>
        {
            public warehousing() : base("Warehousing") { }
        } 
}
```

then your query becomes something like this:

```
   Where<UsersInRoles.rolename, Equal<BQLConstants.warehousing>>,
```

However, I do not recommend to store usernames or existing Acumatica constants as your own [duplicate] constants.

As for PXUIEnabledAttribute, it works like this 
    [PXUIEnabled(typeof(Where<...add your condition here...>))]

I would definitely recommend to take T100, T200 and T300 courses to familiarize yourself with Acumatica customization.

Comment: That is a very cool idea of putting the "a == null" inside PXUIFieldAttribute thank you, But I would like to learn how the constat classes work and how to create/implement the them

Comment: I only now found out the class I wanted call only release in 2019R1 and the server is on 2018R2